# Informal way of saying hello?

Tags: greetings, informal

Is there a more informal way than the standard 你好 to say "hi" or "wazzup" when meeting friends or equal age people of the same age, or is 你好 always appropriate?

Comment: Just say "hi" or "hey"?

Comment: Haha, yes of course, but is there a Chinese word that is equal to that? :)

Comment: Maybe "yo" or "哟". Generally it depends on context and relationship between you and this person you greetings. There're many alternatives, but not precisely equal to "hello", like calling them by nickname, or "吃了没?""去哪啊?""早" etc.

Comment: Just make a sound, like 'haa'. 'ahh' they are not English,  Chinese or any language,  they're just sound

Answer (score 3):

You can say ‘嗨’, which is equivalent to ‘hi’ in English or ‘哈咯’ which translates to ‘hello’ or even ‘哟‘ like another user had mentioned in the comments.